# Changing the value a pointer points to with an alias

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose I have the following function:

```
Table * lookup_set(Table * t, char * key, ValueType value)
{
    int hash = lookup_hash(key);
    char * key_copy = strdup(key);
    Entry * bucket = t->table[hash];
    ...
```

and then later

```
    Entry * new = (Entry *) malloc(sizeof(Entry));
    new->key = key_copy;
    new->value = value;
    new->next = NULL;
    bucket = new;
    return t;
}
```

The value of t->table[hash] won't be changed to new, even though I assigned new to bucket, which I think I set to point to the memory block that t->table[hash] points to. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're changing the `bucket` pointer itself, not the value it points at.

Comment: Sorry, how should I declare `bucket` such that when I set `bucket` to be a new `Entry`, then `t->table[hash]` will also be assigned that new Entry? I want to be able to do things like `bucket = bucket->next` which I don't think I can do with `t->table[hash]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you probably want is something more like:

```
Table * lookup_set(Table * t, char * key, ValueType value)
{
    int hash = lookup_hash(key);
    char * key_copy = strdup(key);
    Entry ** bucket = *t->table[hash];
        :
    Entry * new = (Entry *) malloc(sizeof(Entry));
    new->key = key_copy;
    new->value = value;
    new->next = *bucket;
    *bucket = new;
    return t;
}
```

`bucket` is now a pointer to a pointer, allowing you to change the value of the pointed at pointer.  If you want to move `bucket` down the linked list, you need to use

```
bucket = &(*bucket)->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider making the problem easier to understand:

You have

```
int bucket = X;
```

then later on

```
bucket = y;
```

then later on

```
return x;
```

Understand?

So you need a line somewhere

```
t->table[hash] = new;
```

But be careful of memory leaks.